# How to reset game after card has been chosen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have created a small “guess who” mini game app and I would like to add some more features into it, like restarting the game once it has been won. And what I want is every time the identity card has been chosen I would like it to reset and start a new game but how would I be able to go about that to get my mini game to reset?

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('Guesswho.PNG')
image.show()

image2 = Image.open('IMG_8338_1.PNG')
image3 = Image.open('Susan.JPG')
image4 = Image.open("Charles.JPG")
image5 = Image.open("Bernard.PNG")
image6 = Image.open("David.PNG")
image7 = Image.open("Frans.PNG")

 
def decor(write):
    def wrap():
        print("Guess who!")
        write()
    return wrap()
    
def print_text():
    print("mini mobile game")
decorated = decor(print_text)
print("")

def strike(text):
    result = ''
    for c in text:
        result = result + c + '\u0336'
    return result
```

**The Game**
The game basically starts here and here is where I would like to reset it every time the identity card is found but how would I be able to that?

```
def Game():
    Run = True
    while Run:
    
        guess_Who = input("Guess who: ")
        
        #player one
        if guess_Who == ("Joe Rosberg Male"):
            guess_Who = image2.show() 
            print("Joe is the identity card!")    
        
        
        elif guess_Who == ("Susan Rockwell Female"):
           guess_Who = image3.show()
           print(input("Wrong guess player 2s turn now, What is your guess P2 Please Input name Twice: " + "Card - "+ strike("X Susan Rockwell X")))
              
            
        else:
            ("Wrong move try again!")
            
                                  
            
        #player two
        if guess_Who == ("Charles Jippy Black hat White pants"):
          guess_Who = image4.show()
          print(input("The card Identity card has been choosing, Game has been won!"))
           
        
        elif guess_Who == ("Bernard Bently Male"):
           guess_Who = image5.show()
           print(input("Wrong guess player 2s turn now, What is your guess P2 Please Input name Twice: " + "Card - "+ strike("X Bernard Bently X")))
              
            
            
        
          #player one
        if guess_Who == ("David rillz Male"):
            guess_Who = image6.show() 
            print("David is the identity card!")    
        
        elif guess_Who == ("Fran Rias male"):
           guess_Who = image7.show()
           print(input("Wrong guess player 2s turn now, What is your guess P2 Please Input name Twice: " + "Card - "+ strike("X Fran Rias X")))
            
        else:
            ("Wrong move try again!")           
      
     
Game()
```

Answer (score 0):

Return from `Game` once the identity card has been chosen. Besides that just wrap your function in a loop like:

```
while True:
    Game()
```

Comment: Also, might want to reset the image back to the default

Comment: Could be a little more clearer on what you mean by Return from Game? @theEpsilon

Comment: @user14256016 just put a `return` statement once the identity card has been selected

Comment: This might sounds dumb but could you give me an example.